# Peewee ORM: how to efficiently iterate over a large resultset

Tags: python, peewee

I want my program to start processing rows, as soon as they are received from the MySQL server (many rows and slow connection).

The [docs recommend for querying lots of rows](https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#iterating-over-lots-of-rows): `MyModel.select().iterator()`.

However, it seems that first the DB server sends all the data, before the iterator yields its first result (verified with tcpdump in another terminal).

I tried accomplishing this with the raw DB drivers `MySQLdb` and `pymysql` but there the results seem to get buffered as well.

Is it at all possible? How do other Peewee devs handle iterating over large datasets?

Answer (score 3):

Willem, for this problem, Postgresql provides named cursors (or server-side cursors), which are supported by peewee:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#server-side-cursors

I am not super familiar with MySQL but perhaps it provides something similar?

If not you can always use a chunked iterator.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Could you elaborate on the chunked iterator? I don't quite understand how that would solve the "wait before 2GB of data has arrived before starting processing" issue, given that a normal iterator doesn't start immediately.